# How to get live stream from webcam in opencv ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv

Similar questions are asked many times,but no working solutions.

the following is the code I have used :

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

//Data Structure to store cam.
CvCapture* cap=cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
//Image variable to store frame
IplImage* frame;
//Window to show livefeed
cvNamedWindow("LiveFeed",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while(1)
{
    //Load the next frame
    frame=cvQueryFrame(cap);
    //If frame is not loaded break from the loop
    if(!frame)
        printf("\nno");;
    //Show the present frame
    cvShowImage("LiveFeed",frame);
    //Escape Sequence
    char c=cvWaitKey(33);
    //If the key pressed by user is Esc(ASCII is 27) then break out of the loop
    if(c==27)
       break;
}
//CleanUp
cvReleaseCapture(&cap);
cvDestroyAllWindows();
}
```

My output is ' no ' printed infinitely. ie. no camera feed.
Please help out anyone !!!

Answer (score 1):

maybe there's no camera for index 0 ? try other numbers.

also, since you seem to be pretty new to this, *please avoid the outdated c-api*
use the newer c++ api instead, the old one is no longer actively maintained since 3 years already.

---

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(-1);     // get 'any' cam
    while( cap.isOpened() )   // check if we succeeded
    {
        Mat frame;
        if ( ! cap.read(frame) )
            break;
        imshow("lalala",frame);
        int k = waitKey(33);
        if ( k==27 )
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment..but I have already tried using -1,1 etc.
It didnot work..
I can see video stream in vlc,cheese etc. but not here. I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "-1" to get the first/default Camera, use "CV_CAP_ANY".

```
VideoCapture cap(CV_CAP_ANY);
```